# Waveform from microphone objective c

Tags: cocoa, audio, microphone, waveform

I'm making a cocoa app in Xcode that will analyze microphone input in real time. I've looked around at tutorials and other questions, but they all seem to be dealing with audio files instead of microphone input.

What would I need to use to get audio data from the microphone into an array so I could draw the waveform?